# Is this PCB burned, and is it correct?

Tags: pcb

Okay, so I am a newbie with technology and was wondering if, when soldering, I accidentally burned this PCB and so far, does it match the schematic for the thing I am making? Also, if it is burned, can anyone advise on how to fix it? [image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks, all advice is appreciated, :D!

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Just try it already! The worst thing that will happen is it won't work.

Comment: What are you using for soldering, a blowtorch? o_O

Comment: PTH (plated through-hole) boards like this one are more difficult (than single-sided boards) to work with and not recommended for a beginner, although when properly used they do provide a higher-quality result. Proper soldering technique for PTH boards is shown for example in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYz5nIHH0iY

Comment: And also here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgcPxdnjwt4&index=7&list=PL926EC0F1F93C1837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You burned and delaminated the solder rings from the some holes in the pcb. All that does is make that hole useless. Luckily, you have a ton of other holes available. Practice soldering, and don't keep your iron on the solder rings/pcb for longer than needed.

As for if the circuit matches the schematic, you will find it to be almost improbable that anyone can tell from just a set of pictures like that.

Comment: If I can make an extra suggestion, this is mostly caused by your soldering tip being too hot. If you're serious about soldering, get a TEMPERATURE CONTROLLED soldering iron. Even a cheap one will do.